# Сохранение данных в Firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Подскажите, как правильно прописать в методе UpdateInformation путь к уже ранее загруженному фото профиля, или может сделать запрет на изменение ранее загруженного фото? Так как сейчас при сохранении данных пользователя, строка с ссылкой в firebase на загруженное изображение удаляется.

```
package ru.rdv.viapp;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.HashMap;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button saveSettingsBtn;
    private EditText set_user_name;
    private EditText set_about_me;
    private ConstraintLayout set_edit_profile;
    private ImageButton back_arrow;
    private CircleImageView circleImageView;
    private String currentUserID;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference rootRef;
    private static final int GalleryPick = 1;
    private StorageReference UserProfileImageRef;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;


    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        back_arrow = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.backArrow);
        saveSettingsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_user_settings);
        set_edit_profile = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.settings_edit_profile);
        set_user_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.settings_user_name);
        set_about_me = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.settings_user_about_me);
        circleImageView = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        UserProfileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);


        //Кнопка переходна на страницу изменения профиля
        set_edit_profile.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent Intent = new Intent( SettingsActivity.this, AboutMeEditActivity.class);
            startActivity(Intent);
        });


        //Кнопка назад
        back_arrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        //Кнопка сохранения
        saveSettingsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                UpdateInformation();
            }
        });

        //Получение информации о пользователе
        retrieveUserInformation();

        //Выбрать фото пользователя
        circleImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GalleryPick);
            }
        });
    }



    //Метод сохранения настроек
    private void UpdateInformation() {
        String setName = set_user_name.getText().toString();
        String setAboutMe = set_about_me.getText().toString();


        //Если поле Имя пустое выводим сообщение
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(setName)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Введите имя", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //Если поле О себе пустое выводим сообщение
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(setAboutMe)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Заполните поле о себе", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            HashMap<String, Object> profileMap = new HashMap<>();
            profileMap.put("uid", currentUserID);
            profileMap.put("name", setName);
            profileMap.put("about_me", setAboutMe);

            rootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).setValue(profileMap)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Информация обновлена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(mainIntent);
                           }
                            else {
                                String message = task.getException().toString();
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Произошла ошибка" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

    }


    //Метод загрузки фотографии профиля в Firebase
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==GalleryPick && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null)
        {
            Log.d("MyLog", "Image URI:" + data.getData());
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            circleImageView.setImageURI(data.getData());
                loadingBar.setTitle("Загрузка фотографии");
                loadingBar.setMessage("Пожалуйста подождите");
                loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                loadingBar.show();

                Uri resultUri = data.getData();
                StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");
                filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                final String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                                rootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("profile_image").setValue(downloadUrl).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Фотография успешно загружена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            retrieveUserInformation();
                                            loadingBar.dismiss();

                                        }else {
                                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Произошла ошибка загрузки", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

        }
    }

    //Метод получения информации о пользователе
    private void retrieveUserInformation() {
        rootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID)
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if(snapshot.exists() && snapshot.hasChild("name") && snapshot.hasChild("profile_image")){
                            String retrieveUserName = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String retrieveProfileImage = snapshot.child("profile_image").getValue().toString();
                            String retrieveAboutMe = snapshot.child("about_me").getValue().toString();
                            set_user_name.setText(retrieveUserName);
                            Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).into(circleImageView);
                            set_about_me.setText(retrieveAboutMe);
                        } else if(snapshot.exists() && snapshot.hasChild("name") ) {
                            String retrieveUserName = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String retrieveAboutMe = snapshot.child("about_me").getValue().toString();
                            set_user_name.setText(retrieveUserName);
                            set_about_me.setText(retrieveAboutMe);
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(  SettingsActivity.this,"Введите своё имя", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    }
                });
    }


}
```